# How to temporarily hide an icon on XFce4's panel?

Tags: xfce, icons, panel

I have an icon on the panel that I'd like to hide, but only temporarily, i.e. my mail check icon. There are times I'd like to hide it, so I can focus on work, ignoring E-mails until later.

Removing the icon results in the settings being deleted, which is not a good solution, as re-adding the icon then takes many steps.

How can I temporarily hide an icon in XFce4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Add the following line to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` (create the file if it is missing):

```
#mailwatch-7 image{-gtk-icon-transform: scale(0);}
```

Create the script `toggle-panel-mail`:

```
#!/bin/sh
gtkfile="$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css"
tmp="$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/tmpfile"
sed '/#mailwatch/y/01/10/' "$gtkfile" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$gtkfile"
xfce4-panel --restart
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x toggle-panel-mail` and run it to toggle the icon's visibility.

#### Background

The topic [XFCE4 forum: How can I remove the icons from the panel](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=60813#p60813) suggests to tweak the GTK3 style-sheet to suppress icons; unfortunately it uses a `.tasklist` identifier, while you want the mail widget identifier. How do we find it out? [XFCE forum: GTK3 customization](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11265) explains it:

> [Right click the panel], go to Panel Preferences > Items tab and hover your mouse over the plugin (the name will appear in the tooltip).

Thus I've found `mailwatch-7`. The integer is likely the version number, so do repeat these steps to find out yours.

#### The script

That's essentially a Sed line that flips `0` to `1` and vice-versa only for lines that contain `#mailwatch` (so that it won't mess up other lines if you do use that file for tweaking GTK) and then restarts the panel. Some Seds have a `-i` flag for in-place editing, which could simplify the script. E.g., with GNU Sed, we could simplify it to

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i '/#mailwatch/y/01/10/' "$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css"
xfce4-panel --restart
```

#### Extra resources

- [GTK+ CSS Properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html).
- [`man xfce4-panel`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xfce4-panel/xfce4-panel.1.en.html).